# Docker container not running with Windows system call error

Tags: .net, powershell, docker, containers, docker-run

I am working on trying to run the [`dotnet/core/sdk`](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-sdk/) container in Azure Pipelines. To get everything lined up, I built a PowerShell script that effectively pulls the container and drops the necessary files inside it before running it:

```bsh
$compositeImage = "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0.100-preview4-nanoserver-1809"
docker pull $compositeImage

$targetContainer = ""

Write-Host "Creating container for pre-provisioning..."

($targetContainer = docker create --name builder $compositeImage)

Write-Host $targetContainer

docker ps -a
Write-Host "Copying samples to container..."
$workPath = "C:\Users\dendeli\Documents\Expression"
$scriptPath = "C:\Users\dendeli\Downloads\test2\test2.ps1"

Write-Host "Samples path: " + $workPath
Write-Host "Script path:" + $scriptPath

Write-Host "Executing copy..."
docker cp $workPath builder:__samples

Write-Host "Executing script copy..."
docker cp $scriptPath builder:buildsamples.ps1

Write-Host "Committing changes..."
docker commit builder "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk"

docker run --name newbuilder --rm "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk" powershell
```

The issue comes at the end, when I am executing `docker run`. If I exclude the command to be passed (`powershell`), it all works fine and I see this output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.XYZ]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>
```

However, with the command appended, I am running into a blocker - it errors out:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container 879f2fff5aeaf19ace367d3f713242519238a96944b35b2598f2a3b6010a19fb encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF686739ADB: (caller: 00007FF6866EDF1A) Exception(2) tid(380) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info: {"CommandLine":"powershell","User":"ContainerUser","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\","Environment":{"ASPNETCORE_URLS":"http://+:80","DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER":"true","DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER":"true","NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE":"skip"},"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: @HAL9256 the `run` command will need to instantiate a new container, with a different name, so the unique name should generally not be the blocker.

Comment: ok thanks. I haven't had the opportunity to work with docker so I thought it might have been an easy fix ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
C:\> docker container run -it --rm mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0.100-preview4-nanoserver-1803

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.706]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>powershell
'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

For Powershell 5.1 you'll need the net framework to run it, which wouldn't make sense in a container hosting dotnet core.

`pwsh`works ( Powershell Core).

```
C:\>pwsh
PowerShell 6.2.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS C:\>
```